# Finding the matrix of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

$$T\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 3x_1+5x_2\\ 7x_1-x_2\end{pmatrix}$$ $$T:{\mathbb R}^2 \rightarrow {\mathbb R}^2$$
I have no idea how to start this. Any help would be appreciated. I need to find the transformation matrix T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to make an ansatz (educated guess) of the form of $T$.  You can assume that

$$
T \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

and now compute that

$$
T \left [ \begin{array}{c}
x_1 \\
x_2\\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{array} \right ] \left [ \begin{array}{c}
x_1 \\
x_2\\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{c}
ax_1 + bx_2 \\
cx_1 + dx_2 \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

by ordinary matrix multiplication.  What now must be the values of $a,b,c,d$?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the matrix of a linear transformation by computing what the transformation does to the basis vectors for the domain. The matrix then takes these output vectors as its columns. In your case a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ is formed by two vectors, $\beta_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\beta_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Now, $T(\beta_1) = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 7 \end{bmatrix}$ and $T(\beta_2) = \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$. So the transformation matrix is $A =\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 5 \\
7 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}$. Now,$\ A\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$ will give us $T(\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix})$ for any $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score -2):

The matrix is: $A_{T} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 5 \\ 7 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$. The matrix has the columns $T(e_1),T(e_2)$. And what are $T(e_1) = T((1,0)), T(e_2) = T((0,1))$ ?

Comment: I am not looking for an answer. I still don't know $how$ to do it.